# Weight functions in weighted $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose we have

$$\varphi(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+x}, \ \ \ x>0.$$

Does there exist a constant $C>0$ and a positive function $v(x)$ such that $\varphi(x+y) \leq Cv(x)\varphi(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $v(x+y) \leq v(x)v(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ve^{-|\cdot|} \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $p>0$?

So far all we know is that

$$\varphi(x+y) = \frac{e^xe^y}{1+x+y} \leq e^x\varphi(y)$$

which takes care of the first two properties if we take $v(x) = e^x$, but $ve^{-|\cdot|} \notin L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\varphi(x+y) \le C\,v(x)\,\varphi(y)$ we get
$$
v(x)\,e^{-x}\ge\frac1C\,\frac{\varphi(x+y)}{\varphi(y)}\,e^{-x}=\frac1C\,\frac{1+y}{1+x+y},\quad x,y>0.
$$
Letting $y\to\infty$, we see that $v(x)\,e^{-x}\ge1/C$, which is not in $L^p$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Julian.  We can see that $v(x)e^{-x}$ is bounded from below but we've noticed that for fixed $y$, the right hand side of the inequality is $L^p$ integrable for $p>1$.  Can we bound the right hand side by something integrable in $x$?

Comment: No, ir you want the bound  to be independent  of $y$

Comment: Yes, Julian, this seems to be the case.  I really appreciate all your assistance on this matter.